# How to get class picamera.array in python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

How to get class picamera.array in python??
When I write commands "help('modules')", there is no list 'picamera.array'. There is just picamera. 
I want to capture RGB image and make array from that picture

Answer (score 0):

The way you do that for picamera:

```
import picamera
import picamera.array
```

It's a good question because normally, you would `import picamera` and that would give you access to the attribute `picamera.array`.

However, in the case of `picamera`, in order to avoid adding a hard dependency on `numpy` to `picamera`, the module is not automatically imported by the main `picamera` package and must be explicitly imported.